# How to avoid two queries and replace with join?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I have one model (using **sqlalchemy**) Person. Every Person in this scenario can have only one Job or none (Job is also model). I need to retrieve array of dictionaries (every dictionary represent one person, if person has job nest job dictionary inside person's)

```
[{"name":"Timothy", "age":26},
 {"name":"Jack", "age":34, "job":{"type":"programmer, "money":5}},
 ...
]
```

At the moment I iterate over Persons like this:

```
for person in session.query(PersonModel).all():
    result_person = create_dictionary_for_person()
    job = session.query(JobModel).filter(JobModel.person_id == person.id).first()
    if job:
        result_person['job'] = create_dictionary_for_job()

    some_list.append(result_person)
```

(create_dicti... are simple functions for converting, JobModel has foreign key person_id on PersonModel, all has primary key id).

Is there any way to avoid two queries for every person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a relationship from `PersonModel` to `JobModel` instead, and setting it to eagerly load:

```
class PersonModel(Base):
    ...
    job = relationship('JobModel', lazy='joined')
```

You usually want to specify your relationships from parent to child. If you also need to go from `JobModel` to `PersonModel`, you can specify a [backref](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.backref), which can also be set to eagerly load.